# Returning several values within a CASE expression in subquery and separate columns again in main query

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

My test table looks like this:

```
# select * from a;
 source | target | id
--------+--------+----
      1 |      2 |  1
      2 |      3 |  2
      3 |      0 |  3
```

My query is this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN id<>1
      THEN source
      ELSE 0
      END
      AS source,
    CASE
      WHEN id<>1
      THEN target
      ELSE 0
      END
      AS target
  FROM a
) x;
```

The query seems a bit odd because the CASE expression with the same criteria is repeated for every column. I would like to simplify this and tried the following, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN id<>1
      THEN (source, target)
      ELSE (0, 0)
      END
      AS r
  FROM a
) x;
```

It yields one column with a row value, but I would rather get the two original columns. Separating them with a (r).* or similar doesn't work, because the "record type has not been registered".

I found several questions here with solutions regarding functions returning RECORD values, but none regarding this example with a sub-select.

Actually, there is a quite long list of columns, so repeating the same CASE expression many times makes the whole query quite unreadable.

Since the real problem - as opposed to this simplified case - consists of several CASE expressions and several column groups, a solution with a UNION won't help, because the number of UNIONs would be large and make it unreadable as well as several CASEs.

My actual question is: **How can I get the original columns from the row value?**

Comment: is the id unique?

Comment: Yes, you can see all the data of the table at the top of the question.

Comment: I'm not seeing why a union won't work. Your examples describe a situation where "if id <> 1 return 0 else return value" - classic case for a union no matter how many columns (it'd still be one union of the "dummy" set to the "main" set) - I think you need to refine your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised answer: You can make your query work (fixing the record type has not been registered issue) by creating a `TYPE`:

```
CREATE TYPE stpair AS (source int, target int);
```

And cast the composite value column to that type:

```
SELECT id, (cv).source, (cv).target
FROM (
    SELECT id, CASE
        WHEN id <> 1 THEN (source, target)::stpair
        ELSE (0, 0)::stpair
    END AS cv
    FROM t
) AS x
```

Having said that, it should be far more convenient to use arrays:

```
SELECT id, av[1] AS source, av[2] AS target
FROM (
    SELECT id, CASE
        WHEN id <> 1 THEN ARRAY[source, target]
        ELSE ARRAY[0, 0]
    END AS av
    FROM t
) AS x
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=ddc834c72bbae384573f0df154643441)

Comment: Of course my question was simplified, so a UNION won't help. It's more complicated and contains several such constructions where a couple of columns depend on a CASE branch. If I need, say, 10 UNIONs it also becomes a bit difficult to read and understand. I actually want to get the single columns from the row expression.

Comment: @HolgerJakobs please edit the question and add more cases.

Comment: @HolgerJakobs... it is possible to create a table-like structure (`SELECT 1, 0, 0 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 2)`, left join with it and use COALESCE. But I am guessing you'll have issues with too many coalesces.

Comment: @Holger  see revised answer.

Comment: Yes, these are correct solutions, so I accepted this answer. Using an array is possible only if source and target are of the same type, which is true in this simplified example, but not always in real life. Therefore, I would prefer creating a type and using it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original question. 
If I understood your needs, you want 0 and 0 for `source` and `target` when `id = 1`:

```
SELECT 
  0 AS source, 
  0 AS target 
FROM tablename 
WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  source, 
  target 
FROM tablename 
WHERE id <> 1
```

Comment: I used UNION and not UNION ALL to avoid duplication in case there was a row in the table with 0s for both columns. If there is no case for this then again the result is the same.

Comment: `UNION` is more expensive, because it sorts data. But, more importantly, it doesn't return the same result as the original query in the question. Using your exact example, original query from the question returns the same number of rows as there are in the table. Your query with `UNION` will return less rows.

Comment: Say the table has 100 rows. This `SELECT  source, target FROM tablename WHERE id <> 1` will return 99 rows, right? (I believe there are no dups) + 1 with 0s = 100 rows. Why do you say it will return less rows?

Comment: Here is an example. Rows are `(source, target, id)`. Row 1: `1 2 1` Row 2: `0 0 2`. Original query returns 2 rows. Your query with `UNION` returns 1 row.

Comment: I see what you mean, but should the query return 2 rows: `0 0` and `0 0`? Because this is what the OP's query would return in this case.

Comment: That's the point. In this example the query with `UNION` will return one row. The query with `UNION ALL` will return two rows. To match result of the OP's query you should use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I agree with this case, but is this (2 rows with `0 0`) what the OP wants? I don't know. Anyway, I will edit, although the question has changed since the time it was posted...

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
select source,target,id from a where id <>1 union all select 0 as source,0 as target,id from a where id=1 order by id
```

I have used union all to included cases where multiple records may have ID=1